# How to add a new column on NOT NULL constraint

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, rdbms, postgresql-12

I have a table with 2 columns requested with NOT NULL constraint as shown below

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Val1 | Val2 |
| Val3 | Val4 |

I am trying to add a new column called 'Col3'

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD COLUMN Col3 INTEGER NOT null
```

But it returns an error saying 'having NULL values in a row' Is there any way of which I can use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the new row is supposed to be `NOT NULL`, add a `DEFAULT` clause to the column definition:

```
ALTER TABLE tab
ADD COLUMN Col3 INTEGER NOT null
DEFAULT 0;
```

Alternatively, omit the `NOT NULL`, fill the new column with `UPDATE`, then change the column to be `NOT NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE tab
ALTER col3 SET NOT NULL;
```

After an `UPDATE` on the whole table, you should run `VACUUM (FULL) tab` to get rid of the bloat.